# Have a running script + a website that interact

Tags: python, web

I would like to have one python script running in a loop on my RPi. Basically, this script will take some picture with the camera and try to do some face recognization. 
I also would like to have a website, that would act as a control panel for the script. In this control panel I will be able to suspend the face recognization, to see the logs(who has been seen), and check the unknown people, and configure them.

I know how to do my python script, I've some knowledge in HTML/CSS/JS/WebService, but I've no idea how:

- To have an interaction between the script and the web application(like how to give a flag that would pause the script)
- Host a website on a RPI
- Have the script that could push some things to the website(through a websocket)

Is all that possible? How can I achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever get implemented what you wanted? I also have a similar problem.

Comment: @Nazar, I did, but with Asp.Net Core 2 ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend trying [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/). It's a Python based framework that should let you put together your dashboard. As you'd only be working in one familiar language it shouldn't be too complicated to get your existing code to talk to the front end.

For example, the most basic of basic Flask programs (provided in their docs) which sets up a route and returns a string is:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Flask's [quick start docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#quickstart) are a useful place to begin, and should have enough information to get you up and running with a basic site. I notice that they've updated their site since the last time I visited, and it now includes a useful-looking [page of documentation on deployment options](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/#deployment) - at least one or two of the self-hosted options should be workable on a Pi.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see, but how can I interact between Flask and my python script?(I'm by far not a python expert, more a c# guy). In C# I would have hosted a bidirectional service and push the information.

Also, I plan on having only ONE web page, and just push/update the HTML based on the webservice, I don't know if having routes is the best for that?

Comment: The interaction between Flask and your existing script should be as straightforward as adding an import statement in Flask and calling your existing methods. I made my first shambling steps into Python, from C#, on Flask and it's been relatively painless so far. If you've done a little javascript [this example on github](https://github.com/pallets/flask/tree/master/examples/jqueryexample) might give you a better idea of what a single page site would look like.

Comment: I understand how to make the javascript call to the flask webserver, but how the server will be able to communicate with the other process running the image acquisition? Because if I just import the code, I will have just another instance of it. Or you mean that it's actually my script that will directly host the flask server?

Comment: Python *import* statements are the equivalent of C# *using* statements. All you'd be doing is referencing your original script and calling its methods directly from the web server code. All of the code would become part of the same application.

Comment: I understood that, but still, if I've one python script running and one website running, they can use the same code, but then they will have independant instance with independant variables. It's not having an interaction between the two. 
So with a webserver, how would you have some script that runs in a loop? I don't understand? Because my python script need to run even if there is nobody connected on the website.

Comment: This is heading towards a broader discussion on the workings of python, and the specifics of integrating your particular code with this particular framework. I'm afraid my best suggestion is to go and try a couple of quick test applications to get a feel for it, or go and take a look over some of the flask questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: ??? No my only question is to make the communication between a running script and a web server. You advise me to use `Flesk`as web server, ok, but I still don't know how to communicate with the other process running my python script.